# How to extract the hex value from this data type? - Python cantools

Tags: python, python-3.x, can-bus

I'm using the Python `cantools` library to extract the messages from a CAN dbc file and the data type returned looks like this:

`message('Message_10', 0x146, False, 8, None),`

I need to extract the 2nd value, `0x146` and the message name can change in length so a standard string slice won't consistently work.

My first idea was to convert `message('Message_10', 0x146, False, 8, None),` into a string and then remove everything that doesn't start with `0x` but I suspect there is a better way.

The purpose of this is to pull all of the CAN IDs from a DBC file and create a dictionary with each can ID number as a Key. Then monitor the CAN bus and update the each value in the directory with the data payload associated with each CAN ID on the CAN bus.

Here is a snippet of my code where I originally tried to just extract the message name, which worked but I need the message ID, `0x146`, as the Key in my dictionary to compare with as I look at incoming on the bus

**Anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?**

```
import cantools 

db = cantools.database.load_file('C:\\Users\\Tim\\Desktop\\dbc_file.dbc')

def can_table(db):
    messages = []
    #pprint.pprint(db.messages)
    for msg in range(0, len(db.messages)):
        x = str(db.messages[msg])
        x = x[7:]  # Remove "message"
        x = x.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('\'', '')
        x = x.split(', ') # Split into list
        messages.append(x[0])  # First element is list is the message name

    message_table = {}
    # Populate values as None in dictionary 
    for i in messages:
        message_table[i]=None

    #pprint.pprint(message_table)
    return message_table
```

Examples of what `x` can be after `str()` is called:

```
"message('Message_3', 0x143, False, 8, None)"
"message('Message_2', 0x142, False, 8, None)"
"message('Message', 0x141, False, 8, None)"
"message('Message_with_long_name', 0x201, False, 8, 'comment that explains what this message does')"
```

Result of `dir(db.messages[1])`:

```
   ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_bus_name', '_check_mux', '_check_signal', '_check_signal_lengths', '_check_signal_tree', '_check_signals', '_check_signals_ranges_scaling', '_codecs', '_comment', '_create_codec', '_create_signal_tree', '_cycle_time', '_dbc', '_decode', '_encode', '_frame_id', '_get_mux_number', '_is_extended_frame', '_length', '_name', '_protocol', '_send_type', '_senders', '_signal_groups', '_signal_tree', '_signals', '_strict', 'bus_name', 'comment', 'cycle_time', 'dbc', 'decode', 'encode', 'frame_id', 'get_signal_by_name', 'is_extended_frame', 'is_multiplexed', 'layout_string', 'length', 'name', 'protocol', 'refresh', 'send_type', 'senders', 'signal_choices_string', 'signal_groups', 'signal_tree', 'signal_tree_string', 'signals']
```

Comment: Can you give a few examples of what `x` can be after you assign `str(db.messages[msg])` to it?

Comment: @ronald see edit above

Comment: It looks like ``message`` is already a proper object. Why do you work on ``str(db.messages[msg])`` instead of just ``db.messages[msg]``?

Comment: I work on the `str()` because I need to extract components of the `message` object. So the only way I know how to do that is if I turn it into a string and slice out what I need. I assume there is a better way but I don't know of it @MisterMiyagi

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't it as simple as `x.split(', ')[1]` ?

Comment: Converting the object into a string and then parsing it is *completely insane*.  The `msg` object certainly has attributes corresponding to all of those fields present in the string representation; read the `cantools` documentation, or at least print `dir(msg)` to see what the attributes are named.

Comment: @Ronald that worked perfectly. I didn't know you could through an index after `split()`

Comment: @jasonharper I've gone over the `cantools` docs and can't find anything that explains how to extract the elements from the `messages` data type. But I've added the result from `dir(msg) above, nothing seems to jump out. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke - `msg` is just an integer, it's `db.messages[msg]` that's the actual message object.

Comment: @Tim51: `split()` returns a list ;-)

Comment: @jasonharper you are the man! I found an element called `frame_id` within the `dir(db.messages[msg])` result and it worked perfectly. Thank you for shedding light on how to dive a little deeper into the source. I looked over the docs more times that I can count and I thought I was at a loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second value is frame_id.  Just do `msg.frame_id`.  Do not convert it to a string.

```
for msg in db.messages:
    print(msg.frame_id)
```

From the cantools code, you see that a message is turned into a string with the `__repr__` method.

[`cantools.Message.__repr__`](https://github.com/eerimoq/cantools/blob/master/cantools/database/can/message.py#L907)

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "message('{}', 0x{:x}, {}, {}, {})".format(
        self._name,
        self._frame_id,
        self._is_extended_frame,
        self._length,
        "'" + self._comment + "'" if self._comment is not None else None)
```

Comment: So when inspecting objects like the one described above should one always search for the `__repr__` function in the class to determine how its assembled? @shrewmouse

Comment: `__str__` also but it's best to look at the code or use an IDE like PyDev in Eclipse that will tell you what all of the available options are.

Comment: BTW, if you find yourself doing things like trying to parse strings you're probably on the wrong path.  I know that it was a last resort but just let a warning bell go off in your head.

Comment: Are you aware of anything like PyDev for PyCharm that you would recommend? That's the IDE I work in at the moment. Yeah, I figured the parsing was a red flag glad it was resolved here. @shrewmouse

Comment: I don't use pycharm but I'm shocked that it doesn't have code completion that will inspect the objects for you.